# Find whether point lies in specified polygon MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have following mongoDB document which represents current vehicle position by it's "GPS" field

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565564e2f3e3f5bd2bdfad18"),
        "vehicleId" : 6521,
        "time" : 1448389800,
        "GPS" : "18.55419790592852,73.80579963326454",
        "readings" : {
                "RPM" : {
                        "value" : 1000
                },
                "Speed" : {
                        "value" : 40
                }
        }
}
```

I need to find whether this entry falls inside the polygon specified by co-ordinates:

```
{lat: 18.554321, lng: 73.805231},
{lat: 18.553838, lng: 73.804936},
{lat: 18.553584, lng: 73.806524},
{lat: 18.554240, lng: 73.806546},
{lat: 18.554321, lng: 73.805231}
```

by refering GPS field present in document.

I tried with following query but I am not getting any result:

```
db.data26.find(
   {
     "GPS": {
       $geoWithin: {
          $geometry: {
             type : "Polygon" ,
             coordinates: [ [ [ 73.805231, 18.554321 ], [ 73.804936, 18.553838 ], [ 73.806524, 18.553584 ], [ 73.806546, 18.554240 ], [ 73.805231, 18.554321 ] ] ]
          }
       }
     }
   }
);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Would make your queries much simpler if you change your schema by converting the `GPS` string into an array of longitude and latitude floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GPS field value is string

> "GPS" : "18.55419790592852, 73.80579963326454"

Maybe in order to use geoWithin your GPS should be an array with correct order which is `[long, lat]` like this:
`[73.80579963326454, 18.55419790592852]`

Comment: Well maybe so, but it should also be in longitude and latitude order should it not?